# Detalles de productos con javaScript

Tags: javascript, json, dom

pregunta: estoy intentando avanzar con mi e-commerce y lo estoy realizando con javaScript, hice la generación automática de mis productos mediante el uso del dom, los datos son tomados mediante un Json y genera todos los productos, lo que estoy intentando ahora es que al tocar en un botón de uno de los productos en particular tome su id y genere los datos completos del producto en otro html el cual seria para la descripción de productos, que también se generaría con el uso del dom, intente realizando varios códigos y ninguno me funciono, además me surge la duda de si en caso de conseguirlo, que pasaría si el cliente toca para ver la descripción de otro producto también, ya que la descripción se generaría en un solo html por ende se generarían dos? no encuentro realmente la forma correcta de realizar esto si me pueden guiar y ayudar lo agradecería! muchas gracias
el código hasta el momento es este

```
// lleno mi html con los objetos de forma dinamica

function Products(data) {
    //llena todo lo de la lista
        var dataProduct = data[0].dataProduct
    this.dataProduct = [];

    this.init = function(dataProduct) {
        this.dataProduct = dataProduct;
    }

    this.getById = function(id) {
        return this.dataProduct.filter(product => product.id === id);
    }
    
    this.buildHtmlProduct = function(product) {

        return `
                    <div class="columna-4 ${product.cat}"> 
                        <div class="tarjetaPC">
                            <div class="imgBxPc">
                            <img src="${product.img}" alt="Equipo Matero">
                            </div>
                            <div class="contenidoBxPc">
                                <h3>${product.name}</h3>
                            <div class="ranking">
                                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
                            </div>
                                <h2 class="precioPc">$${product.price}</h2>
                                <a href="productosDetalle.html" onclick="pushDetails(${[0][0[0]]})"><small>Ver Detalle</small></a>
                                <a class="comprarPc" onclick="addToCart(${product.id})">Comprar!</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            `
    }

    this.buildList = function(containerId, sourceProduct) {
        var container = document.getElementById(containerId);
        container.innerHTML = "";
        var html = '';

        this[sourceProduct].forEach((product) => {
            html += this.buildHtmlProduct(product); 
        });
        
        container.innerHTML = html;
    }
}

y el Json esta tal que asi: 

    [
    {
        "dataProduct":
        [
            {      
                "id" : 1,
                "cat": "mates",
                "name" : "Mate 1",
                "img" : "img/EquipoMateroNegroT.png",
                "price" : 999,
                "cantidad": 1,
                "descripcion": "verde"
            },
            {
                "cat": "mates",
                "name" : "Mate 2",
                "id" : 2,
                "img" : "img/EquipoMateroNegroT.png",
                "price" : 1995,
                "cantidad": 1,
                "descripcion": "verde"
            },
            {
                "cat": "mates",
                "name" : "Mate 3",
                "id" : 3,
                "img" : "img/EquipoMateroNegroT.png",
                "price" : 2999,
                "cantidad": 1,
                "descripcion": "verde"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: creo que la mejor forma de mostar detalles de un producto seria en un modal, en caso lo quieras hacer en una pagina aparte, podrias tener una como plantilla y que luego sea rellenada con los datos

Comment: Hola, si lo que estoy intentando es hacerlo en la plantilla aparte, ósea otro html, lo que no me esta saliendo es como tomar los datos de mi data.Json mediante el click en ese producto en particular en el cual leeria el id y lo llevaría a un generador mediante dom en se html en particular

Comment: Lo primero que tendras que hacer es armar una plantilla html, luego haces lo mismo que cuando generas tus productos

Comment: si la plantilla html ya la tengo generada, logre generar de la misma forma los datos pero me genera al igual que en mis productos, todos los objetos de mi Json, lo que yo quisiera es que me genere solo en el cual estoy haciendo click

Comment: se podria resolver con una busquedad, carga tu JSON y luego busca el dato seleccionado por el usuario, si no puedes o no tienes una respuesta hasta mañana hare una :)

Comment: Dale gracias , me voy a quedar toda la noche intentando hacerlo, pero ya llevo 2 dias y no pude jaja asi que en cuanto puedas darme un ejemplo seguro me re salvas. los Json que tengo guardados estan en un archivo aparte llamado data.Json

Comment: Yo lo que haria es encerrar toda la plantilla en una anchor(<a>) que te redireccione hacia la seccion donde muestras las caracteristicas del producto. Para diferenciar uno d otro podrias tomar el product.name a traves de parentnode, child nodes y demas. Al menos asi lo hice en mi pagina y funciona